# Way to make only different state of nav in react-fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, fullpage.js

I'm trying to make a website, and I would like the first section of the landing page (the navigation header) to have a transparent background. The rest of the pages do not need transparent backgrounds.

The landing page is built using [fullPage.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage). I have tried using the scroll event, but it doesn't seem to be supported with fullPage.js. How else can I apply a separate CSS style to just one section using fullPage.js?

I'm adding current Header component code in App.js of React, and confusing to make only one status for the very first landing page's section's header.

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<MainPage />} />
        <Route path='/company' element={<IntroPage />} />
        <Route path='/technology' element={<TechnologyPage />} />
        <Route path='/products' element={<ProductsPage />} />
        <Route path='/RnD' element={<RnDPage />} />
        <Route path='/support' element={<SupportPage />} />
        <Route path='/login' element={<LoginPage />} />
        <Route />
        <Route />
      </Routes>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better solution, but the only one I can think of is to use two different heads. One on the page where it needs to be transparent, and another one on for rest. Give them different ID's, and just set it to transparent on the one where you need it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment ! and that'd be the easiest way to solve this, looks i though this way too dificult and complex. Thanks again !

Comment: Thank you again, but that doesn't looks like right solution, because the 'Header' component is printing from as the very first sequence in App.js.

Will there be a way to make only difeerence status for the first section's of headr component in mainpage?

The structure you can refer is above.

The structures are
 
Header
MainPages
Footer

and i only needed another status in MainPage's the first section's header

Thank you so much!

Comment: Just to clarify. You have a header which is initiated in the Router. Said header is showing successfully on all jsx pages/routes, but you would like the styling to be different on just one of the pages/one route? Is this correct?

Comment: Exactly !
Really thanks for your replying,

With out any doubt, that's really clear, in addition, the only one page is the part of the first page, which is 'MainPage'(LandingPage actually), made of fullpage.js.

I just only needed one section to make different header, and also i'm new in development. Thanks for giving me a hand eskiltb !